# input format data in json with double curly braces

Tags: python, json, format

I get json from the other server like

```
{"field":"zxczxczcx_{{name}}_qweqweqwe"}
```

So the question is how to format that value?
I've tried

```
d = {"field":"zxczxczcx_{{name}}_qweqweqwe"}
d['field'].format('any_string')
```

But it just remove one pair of curly braces and output

```
"zxczxczcx_{name}_qweqweqwe"
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the replace method?

```
d = {"field":"zxczxczcx_{{name}}_qweqweqwe"}
d['field'] = d['field'].replace('{{name}}','any_string')
print(d)
```

Based on your comments (this uses the re module (regular expressions) to find the {{x}} pattern) :

```
import re

tokens_to_replace = re.findall('{{.*}}',d['field'])
for token in tokens_to_replace:
    d['field'] = d['field'].replace(token,d[token[2:-2]])
```

tokens_to_replace will have value: ['{{name}}']

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I have the problem that this values in double curly might be declared in this incoming json, like
`{"name":"the_name","field":"zxczxczcx_{{name}}_qweqweqwe"}`
and I don't know the exact name of this incoming parameters

Comment: In that case:  replace('{{name}}',d['name'])

Comment: yeah, but in that case I need to parse this json and figure out what fields I got in double curly 
I mean the first argument of replace method
I understood how to solve my problem by your plan, I was just thinking if there is any easier way